# wiremock issue when upgrading to Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, wiremock

When upgrading my Spring Boot 2.5 to 3.0 , I am facing some issues with Wiremock, probably due to the move to jakarta namespace. Even upgrading to latest `wiremock-jre8` , ie `2.35.0` (as of december 2022) doesn't seem to help. I get this error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/DispatcherType

    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty9.JettyHttpServerFactory.getServerConstructor(JettyHttpServerFactory.java:37)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty9.JettyHttpServerFactory.<clinit>(JettyHttpServerFactory.java:30)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks like this is a know issue related to jakarta namespace and Jetty 11 support, that will take a while to get properly fixed :

https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/1760

As indicated in the issue, using  `wiremock-jre8-standalone` instead of `wiremock-jre8` helps working around the issue, until it gets properly fixed in Wiremock 3.x

**Edit, Oct 2023** : these are now available and should help :

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wiremock/wiremock-standalone/3.2.0
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock-jre8-standalone/3.0.1

Answer (score 2):

E.g. **Wiremock version 1.58** works (if you don't mind using an older version) in combination with Spring Boot 3

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-jre8-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

or for Spring boot 3:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wiremock</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use wiremock version 3.0.0-beta2+ to solve the issue. I just tested it.

https://groups.google.com/g/wiremock-user/c/knTaDyBY70Q